# By adding a "change" method to a model my view is no longer bound to it?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am still trying to wrap my head around how Backbone.js works. I have a Model that I want to run a calculation whenever one of the attributes is changed.

```
window.Print = Backbone.Model.extend({
    change: function () {
        this.set({ totalTime: this.calculateTime() }, {silent: true});
    }
```

Which works. Whenever an attribute is modified, the "change" method fires and the calculation is done.

The problem is that having the "change" method in there, my view no longer re-renders on a change (I am assuming it no longer is bound to the change method?). If I take it out, my view works as expected.

My view looks like this:

```
window.TimeView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.template = _.template($('#template').html());
    },
    render: function(){
        var renderedContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(renderedContent);
        return this;
    }
});
```

I have a feeling I am approaching this incorrectly... Should my calculation not be done within the Model? Where should it be done? (Backbone is the first time I have tried to implement MVC)

**EDIT:**
I figured it out. I should be binding the code to change, not overwriting it.

```
window.Print = Backbone.Model.extend({  
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind('change', function() {
            this.set({ totalTime: this.calculateTime() }, {silent: true});
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: you should add your solution in an answer instead of in your question, then you can accept it and it might help out other users that search for similar issues. then this question can be closed and archived :)

Comment: It said I have to wait 8 hours before I can do that :P. Something about being a new user.

Comment: understood :P thats spam protection really, but you can just come back tomorrow and do it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was overwriting the render method, the way I found that works is to bind the actions I wanted *to* the method when I initialize the function.

```
window.TimeView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind('change', function() {
            this.set({ totalTime: this.calculateTime() }, {silent: true});
        });
    }
});
```